# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in DynamicDotNetTWAIN.dll

Tags: c#

I was implementing Dynamic Dot Net Twain OCR function in Asp.Net MVC web project, it gives the output when i give OCRResultformat as PDFPlainText but when i give OCRResultFormat as PDFImageOverText it throws an Exception

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in DynamicDotNetTWAIN.dll"........

Any help would be highly appreciated.
My code is as follows.

```
 DynamicDotNetTwain dynamicDotNetTwain1 = new DynamicDotNetTwain();
      dynamicDotNetTwain1.LicenseKeys = "A3EDADA92DCE76E49D628E3AE59AC978;A3EDADA92DCE76E447421F637B0A5E35";
      dynamicDotNetTwain1.IfThrowException = true; 
      string TessDataPath = @"E:\metsi\E-archive source\Source\Source\EArchive.Web\Redistributable\Resources\";
      dynamicDotNetTwain1.OCRTessDataPath = TessDataPath;
      dynamicDotNetTwain1.OCRLanguage = "eng";
      dynamicDotNetTwain1.OCRResultFormat = (Dynamsoft.DotNet.TWAIN.OCR.ResultFormat)2;
      string strDllPath = @"E:\metsi\E-archive source\Source\Source\EArchive.Web\Redistributable\Resources\OCR\";
      dynamicDotNetTwain1.OCRDllPath = strDllPath;
      //string[] source = new string[] { @"E:\metsi\E-archive source\Source\Source\EArchive.Web\Documents\0606dbbd-3d24-44b4-8700-17ece39f873e.tif" };
      dynamicDotNetTwain1.LoadImage(sourcePath);
      //short a= dynamicDotNetTwain1.CurrentImageIndexInBuffer;
      if (dynamicDotNetTwain1.CurrentImageIndexInBuffer < 0)
      {
          return false;
      }
      //int bottom = dynamicDotNetTwain1.GetImage(dynamicDotNetTwain1.CurrentImageIndexInBuffer).Height;
      //int left = 0;
      //int right = dynamicDotNetTwain1.GetImage(dynamicDotNetTwain1.CurrentImageIndexInBuffer).Width;
      //int top = 0;
      //IndexList index = new IndexList();
      //index.Add(0);
      byte[] sbytes = null;
      sbytes = dynamicDotNetTwain1.OCR(dynamicDotNetTwain1.CurrentSelectedImageIndicesInBuffer);

      if (sbytes != null && sbytes.Length > 0)
      {
         System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, sbytes);
      }
      else
      {
          System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, null);
      }
      return true;
     }
```

Comment: It's definitely a bug in DynamicDotNetTWAIN.dll. If it's private bits, how can others help?

Comment: @qxg the demo i downloaded works well for all OCRResultFormat......but when i implement it in a project it throws an exception that also when the OCRResultFormat is set to PDFImageOverText... other format works

Comment: An SOE can strike anywhere and the underlying cause does not often have anything to do with the code that throws it.  Makes them hard to debug, the reason they named a popular programmer's website after it.  Assuming that a product by a commercial company that's been around for a long time triggered this bug should *never* be the first assumption.  Spend time in the debugger, single-step code, pay attention to the debugger's Stack Trace window.  If you are then still convinced that it is a bug in the product then you need to contact the company for support.

Comment: You can contact [Dynamsoft support](http://www.dynamsoft.com/Company/Contact.aspx) for help.